# API REST funciona localmente, porém não funciona no TOM CAT

Tags: spring, tomcat

Estou subindo uma API Rest localmente e fazendo requisições normalmente com o POSTMAN nesta API, porém, quando subo essa mesma API no Tomcat, ela simplesmente da erro 404 e não tenho acesso a nenhum dos métodos da mesma.

Este é o meu POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.consiste</groupId>
    <artifactId>xtr-util</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <name>xtr-util</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>lotus-domino</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>xtr-util</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin
                </artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Nem mesmo o método mais simples funciona no tomcat.

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/session")
public ResponseEntity<String> checkConnection() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Conexão Estabelecida com a API", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Obs:

Rodando localmente eu vejo a execução do Spring, porém ao subir a aplicação no TOMCAT não aparece esta execução, poderia esse ser o erro?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve seguir as orientações conforme a [documentação do Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

1) Deixar a dependência do servidor embarcado como `provided`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2) Alterar o packaging do seu `pom.xml` para `<packaging>war</packaging>` (você já fez isso)

3) Para gerar o WAR, utilizar a goal `package` do Maven, também conforme apontado pela [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)

Um exemplo de `pom.xml` para deploy tradicional pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional/pom.xml).

Comment: Vou ver se tem algo na documentação que me ajude, obrigado

Comment: Infelizmente já estava utilizando essa dependência, e continua não funcionando

Comment: Você por acaso alterou o context path da aplicação? Apresenta algum erro na inicialização?

Comment: não apresenta nenhum erro de inicialização, simplesmente quando chamo as rotas pelo tomcat existe o erro: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.

Onde seria o context path da aplicação?

Eu tenho essa requisição: @RequestMapping("/api")

E chamo  @GetMapping("/session")

Comment: Adicionei um detalhe no final, se puder dar uma olhada.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro provavelmente é a razão por não estar funcionando.